# bmesh from_edit_mesh points to old dead bmesh after free

Tags: bmesh

I've been struggling with a bmesh problem for a while now and I can't wrap my head around it. When I free my bmesh data and try to make a new bm instance with the same object, it points to the old freed data.

Simplified code snippet:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) #creates new bm
verts = bm.verts
for vert in verts:
    vert.co[2] += 1
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free()

me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) #points to old dead bm (memory pointer is the same)
verts = bm.verts
for vert in verts:
    vert.co[2] -= 1
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free()
```

One thing that does work is switching the mode twice like this:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) #creates new bm
verts = bm.verts
for vert in verts:
    vert.co[2] += 1
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free() 

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()
bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle()

me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) #creates new bm
verts = bm.verts
for vert in verts:
    vert.co[2] -= 1
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free()
```

This is however something I really don't want to do because it's just ugly and it shouldn't be necessary.

Running the second script twice will crash unless you switch mode twice before running it again.

Turning just this part into an operator will also crash if you run it twice without switching modes twice between executions.

```
obj = bpy.data.objects["Cube"]

me = obj.data
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me) #creates new bm
verts = bm.verts
for vert in verts:
    vert.co[2] += 1
bmesh.update_edit_mesh(obj.data)
bm.free()
```

How can I avoid this problem in a nicer way? I don't want people using my add-on to have to switch mode twice if they want to execute the same operator twice. But I also would like to not switch modes constantly in my code

Comment: Probably, bm = bmesh.new() then bm.from_mesh( obj.data ) will work avoiding the edit mode problem. You can then bm.free() and get a new bm = bmesh.new() for the next obj

Comment: Problem is, I need to do this in edit mode. and if I use bm = bmesh.new() then bm.from_mesh(obj.data) before I free my bm data, then I am freeing the wrong data and the chance for memory leaks increases. (I'm working on a massive add-on where performance is quite important)

Comment: What I don't get is why editing/modifying the same object multiple times in the same edit mode session?

Comment: The addon has a lot of operators. some of these operators are usually executed one after another without leaving edit mode (some need some selected verts as input).

Comment: @Singulasar wouldn't it make sense to create the bmesh once and keep a reference to it for the subsequent operations?

Comment: Testing a bit, I think you'll have the same unique bmesh during an edit session, so freeing it should be unnecessary. Typically, once update_edit_mesh is done, it's not possible to use the result of from_edit_mesh a second time. And the doc says: "The BMesh is freed automatically, typically when the script finishes executing. However in some cases its hard to predict when this will be and its useful to explicitly free the data." So don't think there is a possible memory leak here. As I understand it, free is usefull to free memory in order to work another bmesh from another object

Comment: Getting rid of the free does solve the problem @lemon 
I will leave it like this unless someone comes up with something better. It does feel like strange behaviour that a new instance can't be made after freeing. 
I am pretty paranoid of sentences like "it's hard to predict when this will be" I noticed that if I don't free the data it keeps pointing to the same memory location. So it does keep the bmesh in memory until I leave edit mode. I was hoping I could avoid this since I'm working on high poly meshes

But thank you, it did solve my problem and I learned some more about inner workings

Comment: From my experimentation, using `bmesh.from_edit_mesh` automatically frees the __bm__ when edit mode is toggled. You could try using `bm.from_mesh`.